# Solving simultaneous equations in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have following test program. My query is two folded: (1) Some how the solution is giving zero and (2) Is it appropriate to use this `x2= np.where(x > y, 1, x)` kind of conditions on variables ?  Are there any constrained optimization routines in Scipy ?

```
a = 13.235
b = 70.678

def system(X, a,b):
    x=X[0]
    y=X[1]

    x2= np.where(x > y, 1, x)    

    f=np.zeros(3)
    f[0] = 2*x2 - y - a
    f[1] = 3*x2 + 2*y- b


    return (X)


func=  lambda X: system(X, a, b)

guess=[5,5]
sol =  optimize.root(func,guess)
print(sol)
```

edit: (2a) Here with `x2= np.where(x > y, 1, x)` condition, two equations becomes one equation. 
(2b) In another variation requirement is: `x2= np.where(x > y, x^2, x^3)`. Let me comments on these two as well. Thanks !

Comment: @erip, LP algorithms cannot handle nonlinear equations. Isnt it true ?

My typical equations are only representative. They are in fact log and exp forms.

Answer (score 1):

First up, your `system` function is an identity, since you `return X` instead of `return f`. The return should be the same shape as the `X` so you had better have

```
f = np.array([2*x2 - y - a, 3*x2 + 2*y- b])
```

Next the function, as written has a discontinuity where x=y, and this is causing there to be be a problem for the initial guess of (5,5). Setting the initial guess to (5,6) allows for the the solution [13.87828571,  14.52157143] to be found rapidly.

With the second example, again using an initial guess of [5,5] causes problems of discontinuity, using [5,6] gives a solution of [  2.40313743,  14.52157143].

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

def system(X, a=13.235, b=70.678):
    x = np.where(X[0] > X[1], X[0]**2, X[0]**3)
    y=X[1]    
    return np.array( [2*x - y - a, 3*x + 2*y - b])

guess = [5,6]
sol = optimize.root(system, guess)
print(sol)
```